# Associate clsid with Runtime Class for winrt::create_instance Function to Late Bind Runtime Class in External DLL

Tags: winapi, winui-3

How can a Guid be associated with a Runtime Class to be used in the function call winrt::create_instance, so a winrt Runtime Class can be late bound? I don't see how in MIDL 3.0--though Interfaces work with uuid and version. Is this the answer to late binding in WinRT?

Comment: Check out winrt::get_activation_factory https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/get-activation-factory or winrt::try_get_activation_factory https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/try-get-activation-factory

Comment: I want an interface from a class in an in-proc, instanced by passing a guid. Hence create<Interface>(guid clsid);

@RemyLebeau it needs to be defined in the idl, regardless of if this means I address it in the in behind code to implement it.

Comment: Why do you want to use a guid? If you have an .idl file or winmd metadata, you don't need this to instantiate a WinRT object. Not clear what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm going to pass on this discussion. The function is there. Obviously WinRT is creating an underlying class with a CLSID based on my knowledge of the COM/like plumbing and I want o know how to get and set it. My logic is my own and would take more time than I'd like to explain. WRL was formalized this way, and COM ProxyServers was a great way to late bind. I can use COM if I have to.

Comment: And it's not the Guid passed back from get_guid<Namespace::Class>(); because that returns the Interface of the Runtime Class, which itself hides the implementation, as far as I understand.

Comment: winrt::create_instance is a wrapper on CoCreateInstance for regular COM objects because C++/WinRT also has lots of COM utilities beyond WinRT. You don't use CoCreateInstance for WinRT activatable types.

Comment: I guess I'll have to fall back on COM. Answering your earlier question a bit, I am out on a limb designing my own in-house computing software for science and engineering, I need to be able to host hundreds of solvers and their updates generically. That's why. I was anticipating your last reply.

Comment: It is also handy to be able to update a project xml with say, a new rendering pipeline from the community, without having to rebuild the core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know how to use winrt::create_instance, but I took a really deep look into base.h. I found plenty of guts to late bind to a WinRT component dll using def calls and interop. This is my solution to the problem. It works. Choosing the right way to hold IUnknown was important, and there was some specifics I'm still working out; like why I have to wrap the IUnknown in a winrt::impl::abi_t<> (WinRT/COM conversion?). Using the following code you simply load the dll by file name (with qualified path if not in in the executable directory), and call the class according to it's runtime namespace.classname. It is absolutely not necessary to add the activatableclass to the Packackage.appxmanifest or to reference the winmd. A search shows a lot of people looking for this, but there is a general reluctance to point this out. It's just like COM really, with its own quirks.

```
UINT32 ret = 0;

void* dllHandle = WINRT_IMPL_LoadLibraryW(L"Project.dll");

if (!dllHandle) { throw; };

void* pProc = WINRT_IMPL_GetProcAddress(dllHandle, "DllGetActivationFactory");
auto DllGetActivationFactory = reinterpret_cast<int32_t(__stdcall*)(void* classId, void** factory)>(pProc);

static const WCHAR* cname = L"namespace.classname";
const UINT32 cnamelen = wcslen(cname);

HSTRING hcname = NULL;
HSTRING_HEADER header;
HRESULT hr = WindowsCreateStringReference(cname, cnamelen, &header, &hcname);

com_ptr< winrt::impl::abi_t<winrt::Windows::Foundation::IActivationFactory> > oCOMActivationFactory{ nullptr };
ret = (*DllGetActivationFactory)(&header, oCOMActivationFactory.put_void());

com_ptr< winrt::impl::abi_t<winrt::Windows::Foundation::IUnknown> > iObj{ nullptr };
ret = oCOMActivationFactory.get()->ActivateInstance(iObj.put_void());

winrt::com_ptr<ProxyServer::ImplementationInterface> iImplementationInterface{ nullptr };
winrt::copy_from_abi(iImplementationInterface, iObj.as<ProxyServer::ImplementationInterface>());

iImplementationInterface.get()->MyFunction();
       
oCOMActivationFactory.detach();

WindowsDeleteString(hcname);
```